# Class 'RdKafka\\Conf' not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache-kafka, librdkafka, php-rdkafka

I encounter an error using https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka

I followed the installation but still encounter an error using the class.

Installation process:

```
- sudo apt install php-pear

- sudo apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev

- sudo pecl install rdkafka
```

Enable PHP-extension in PHP config. Add to php.ini

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini

extension=rdkafka.so
```

Restart apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Code :

```
    $conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
    $conf->set('log_level', (string) LOG_DEBUG);
    $conf->set('debug', 'all');
    $rk = new \RdKafka\Producer($conf);
    $rk->addBrokers("10.0.0.1:9092,10.0.0.2:9092");
```

Composer.json

```
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    "ext-rdkafka": "*",
    ...
```

Error:

```
"Class 'RdKafka\\Conf' not found"
```

What's wrong with my installation?
why `RdKafka\Conf` class not found?

Comment: Did you check whether the extension was **really** enabled, for example through checking this in `phpinfo`? Also, how is this problem related to Laravel?

Comment: @NicoHaase oh! when I run this command  `php -m` I saw the extension but when I add this code in php  `dd(get_loaded_extensions());` I cannot see the rdkafka extension. How to solve this?

Comment: @Kenneth Did you check that the extension is enabled in both FPM and CLI php configuration files (yes there are two, one for command line and the other for the service) OR  maybe the PHP process did not restart with the restart of apache. try restarting it directly.

Comment: @N69S I restarted the apache and my laptop. But FPM did not load the rdkafka extension

Comment: you need to enable rdkafka in php.ini that is loaded by apache.. check using `phpinfo` to get the path of php.ini

Comment: @Kenneth have you manage to fix the issue? I'm encountering the same problem.